# How do I find address of a global variable in Ollydbg?

Tags: ollydbg, address

I have the line

```
CMP BYTE PTR DS:[EAX+1620], 0
```

How do I find the memory address of `EAX+1620` so I can monitor it in ollydbg? I click it and nothing helpful comes up in the context box at the bottom of the window.

Screenshot here, unnecessary info obscured:

[image]

Using `Follow in Dump` -> Selection on this line will take me to address `00A9612A`, but I need to find `EAX+1620`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if eax is valid address you can follow in dump from the information pane 
(small pane between cpu window and dump window)

see screen shot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. As you can hopefully see in my screenshot the line with the CMP and the [EAX]  in question is selected, but there is no text in the box below, which is what's tripping me up.

My EAX register shows 02C10A7C, which is outside of the maximum used memory address 00AE1FFA.

I'm new to Ollydbg, is there a setting somewhere that might enable/disable those hints in that box?

Comment: Your answer was correct. I restarted olly, reloaded the exe, and tried it again and the address was correctly displayed in the address box. Must have had something to do with where in the program it was when it hit the break.